# error while parsing json which is obtained from Gson

Tags: json, hashmap, gson

I have converted the Hashmap to json using GSON and the json string is like following:

```
 {"records":[{"three":"chingi0","two":"Marge0","five":"Bart0","four":"Maggie0","one":"Homer0"},{"three":"chingi1","two":"Marge1","five":"Bart1","four":"Maggie1","one":"Homer1"}]}
```

but while parsing this string using json it gives me following error:

**org.json.JSON.typeMismatch**

following is my code snippet

```
JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(str);//str is the json string
 JSONObject json_data;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               //here i am accessing the data from json string

            }
```

how can i solve this?

here is my stacktrace:

> org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"records":[{"three":"chingi0","two":"Marge0","four":"Maggie0","five":"Bart0","one":"Homer0"},{"three":"chingi1","two":"Marge1","four":"Maggie1","five":"Bart1","one":"Homer1"}]}
>   of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: where do you get the error? can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: it shows error while converting to jsonArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the error says it all, what you are actually getting is an Object containing an array, so what you should do is:

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(str);
```

and then you'll have the array contained in this object.